# Problems getting data configured properly in an R tibble

Tags: r, tibble

I have been struggling for some time to get my R tibble object in a state that I can use. Here is my current object.

```
str(myresults)
Classes ‘tbl_time’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   433 obs. of  2 variables:
$ DateTime  : POSIXct, format: "2018-07-28 21:00:00" "2018-07-28 22:00:00" ...
$ ordercount: int  1 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 1 1 ...
   - attr(*, "index")= language ~DateTime     
   - attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
   - attr(*, "time_zone")= chr ""
```

I then want to execute the following but get the error

```
myresults <- myresults %>% 
                time_decompose(ordercount) %>% 
                anomalize(remainder) %>% 
                time_recompose()
```

> Error: 'get_index_col' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tibbletime'

I am reading my data from SQL Server, which automatically creates a data frame. Then I have to manipulate the data frame to get it into a state that that can handle the last command above (i.e. convert the factor to date + convert data frame to a tibble).

If I read the data straight from a csv file it goes straight into a tibble and the command executes perfectly.

I've tried so many different ways / functions to get this to work but getting to the point where I have nothing else to try.

I'm sure there's something simple out there that will help but I'm fairly new to R.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have included the code and data below.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(anomalize)
    library(RODBC)

    dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL         Server};server=gbuksvr1.ktest.com;database=myDB;trusted_connection=true')

    myresults <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, "select convert(varchar(30), [date]) + ' ' + [hour] as DateTime, ordercount from my_anomaly_data where site = 'keysite' and paymenttype = 'cash' order by datetime")

    myresults$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(strptime(x = as.character(myresults$DateTime), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))

    myresults <- as_tbl_time(myresults, DateTime)

    myresults <- myresults %>% time_decompose(ordercount) %>% anomalize(remainder) %>% time_recompose()
```

And the data (an extract of it)...

datetime,ordercount
2018-07-28 21:00,1
2018-07-28 22:00,1
2018-07-28 22:00,3
2018-07-29 00:00,1
2018-07-29 03:00,3
2018-07-29 04:00,1
2018-07-29 05:00,3
2018-07-29 07:00,1
2018-07-29 08:00,1
2018-07-29 08:00,1
2018-07-29 09:00,1
2018-07-29 09:00,3
2018-07-29 11:00,3
2018-07-29 13:00,4
2018-07-29 14:00,1
2018-07-29 14:00,1
2018-07-29 14:00,4
2018-07-29 15:00,2
2018-07-29 16:00,4
2018-07-29 16:00,1
2018-07-29 17:00,1
2018-07-29 17:00,2
2018-07-29 18:00,1
2018-07-29 18:00,4
2018-07-29 19:00,5
2018-07-29 20:00,2
2018-07-29 20:00,7
2018-07-29 21:00,1

Comment: Please include the data in reproducible form, `dput(head(myresults, 20))`, and include all packages that you use.

Comment: Updated to include all my code and some sample data

Comment: > dput(head(myresults, 20))
structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1532808000, 1532811600, 
1532811600, 1532818800, 1532829600, 1532833200, 1532836800, 1532844000, 
1532847600, 1532847600, 1532851200, 1532851200, 1532858400, 1532865600, 
1532869200, 1532869200, 1532869200, 1532872800
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), ordercount = c(1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 1L)), .Names = c("DateTime", "ordercount"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = c("tbl_time", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), index = ~DateTime, time_zone = "")
>